# Understanding posets and lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying Judson's text in abstract algebra that asks me to prove or disprove if the set of nonzero integers with the relation: $a \leq b$ if  $a|b$ is a lattice.  I'm stuck because I'm missing some understanding of the concepts on two levels:

1. On a very basic level, I'm not understanding the definition of a lattice.  I need to show that for every pair $(a,b)$ where $a,b$ in the set, that this pair has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound in the set.  Because every poset is reflexive by definition, for any pair $a,b$ (assume $a \ne b$), $a\leq a$ and $b \leq b$.  So, if $a \leq b$, then the greatest lower bound would just be $a$ because every other element $a'$ in the set $\leq a$ would necessarily have to be $\leq a$.  So, greatest lower bound is just $a$.  Likewise, least upper bound is just $b$.  So... every poset is a lattice. (?)
2. Consider the problem of determining whether or not the relation $a \leq b$ if $a|b$ over the nonzero integers is a lattice.  Well, clearly for any $(a,b)$ in the set (which means $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$), $\pm \text{lcm}(a,b)$ divides $a,b$ and $a,b$ are divisible by $\pm \text{gcd}(a,b)$.  So, if a least upper bound exists, it should be $\pm \text{lcm}(a,b)$.  Or, if a greatest lower bound exists, it should be $\pm \text{gcd}(a,b)$?  The minus sign is what's throwing me off in this particular example.

Thank you.

Comment: See [Lattice (order))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)): "It consists of a *partially ordered set* in which **every pair of elements has** a unique supremum (also called a least upper bound or join) and a unique infimum (also called a greatest lower bound or meet)."

Comment: "The natural numbers also form a lattice under the operations of taking the greatest common divisor and least common multiple, with divisibility as the order relation: $a\leq b$ if $a$ divides $b$. 1 is bottom; 0 is top."

Comment: I suppose it should be positive integers. Otherwise, we get $1|-1$ and $-1|1$, and yet $1\neq-1$; the same for any other integer. Thus you only get a per-ordered set, from which you can obtain a poset (by identifying $n$ with $-n$) which is a lattice.

Comment: Ok, @MauroALLEGRANZA and amrsa, thank you.  But can you explain to me if anything is wrong with my logic in part $1$.  Certainly, not every poset is a lattice, right?

Comment: What is wrong in your part 1 is that you're just showing that there is lup and glb of $a$ and $b$, whenever $a\leq b$ (that is, $a|b$). But you need to show it for every pair of elements $a$ and $b$, and the result is what you hint at in part 2. These elements exist for reasons which are beyond the scope of order theory (it's basic arithmetics). And all of this is only possible by using the trick I refer to above, or you ran into the problem I mentioned and Esgeriath too. See here how it's done: [Preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder#Preorders_and_partial_orders_on_partitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not every poset is a lattice, because not every two elements have to be in relation. Consider $(\mathbb{N}, |)$ (natural numberes ordered by divisibility): 6 and 14 are not comparable, since neither divides the other.
   The join is 42, and the meet is 2.
2. Your example is not even a poset, because $|$ is not antisymmetric on $\mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}$: we have $-n|n$ and $n|-n$, but $n\neq -n$.
   If we were playing with $(\mathbb{N}, |)$, the $\operatorname{gcd}$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ would make join and meet respectively as you expected.

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: There's something odd in your first statement. The reason for which not every poset is a lattice is that in some posets there are elements $a$ and $b$ such that there is not a glb or lub of $a$ and $b$. I say it's odd and not just wrong because in what follows you seem to be very aware of that. Perhaps you didn't express right, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @armsa, I agree that the first statement of Esgeriath is not complete.  I mean, clearly $6$ and $14$ are not relation in this example, but they still have both lub and glb.  Definition of lattice does not require the pair to be related.  Can you give an example of a poset which is not a lattice?  I'm having trouble seeing it.

Comment: @Doug That's what I wrote in the comment. As for an example of a poset which is not a lattice, consider $A=\{a,b\}$ with the binary relation $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$. That is, the relation is equality, or, in other words, two elements are related iff they're equal. These are called anti-chains. See also [Examples of non-lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Examples_of_non-lattices).

Comment: Ok.  I get it now.